# What is the optimal approach to parse OWASP ZAP XML reports in Python and export to Excel with table output?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, export-to-excel

I am currently working on a Python program that parses OWASP ZAP XML reports and generates an Excel file with the extracted information. While I have made progress in parsing the XML data, I'm encountering formatting issues when exporting it to Excel. Additionally, I have concerns about the effectiveness of my current parsing code.

Here's an overview of my project:

I have a collection of OWASP ZAP XML reports that need to be programmatically parsed.
The objective is to extract specific details from these reports, such as vulnerabilities, affected URLs, severity levels, and recommendations.
For XML parsing, I have begun exploring Python's built-in XML parsing capabilities, specifically `xml.etree.ElementTree` to navigate and extract the required data fields.
The XML reports have a structure similar to the following snippet:

[image: snippet of the xml]

However, I am facing two main challenges:

Formatting the Excel output according to specific requirements: I need the exported Excel file to have a table for every vulnerability with descriptions, host ,and ports , and all the inormation about the vulnerability, I am trying to use xlsxwriter but I can't seem to make this table.

Assessment of the current XML parsing code: I am uncertain whether the code snippet I am using for XML parsing is optimal. I would appreciate any feedback on whether it adequately extracts the necessary information from the OWASP ZAP XML reports or if there are more efficient alternatives. Here is the code snippet I am currently using for XML parsing:

```
    def process_xml_folder(self):
        """
        Process XML files in the specified folder and extract site and alert information.
        """
        for filename in os.listdir(self.path_zap):
            if filename.endswith('.xml'):
                tree = Et.parse(os.path.join(self.path_zap, filename))
                root = tree.getroot()

                # Extract site information
                for site in root.findall('.//site'):
                    self.site_name = site.get('name')
                    self.site_host = site.get('host')
                    self.site_port = site.get('port')
                    self.site_ssl = site.get('ssl')
                    self.sites.append([self.site_name, self.site_host, self.site_port, self.site_ssl])

                    # Extract alert information
                    for alert in site.findall('.//alertitem'):
                        alert_ref = alert.find('alertRef').text
                        alert_name = alert.find('alert').text
                        alert_risk_code = alert.find('riskcode').text
                        alert_confidence = alert.find('confidence').text
                        alert_risk_desc = alert.find('riskdesc').text
                        alert_confidence_desc = alert.find('confidencedesc').text
                        alert_desc = alert.find('desc').text
                        alert_instances = alert.find('instances').text
                        self.alerts.append([
                            self.site_host, alert_name, alert_risk_code, alert_confidence,
                            alert_risk_desc, alert_confidence_desc, alert_desc, alert_instances
                        ])
                        self.alert_ref.append(alert_ref)
```

Comment: "optimal" is up to you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking for feedback on working code should be posted on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).